# How to use custom messages from the Server NodeJS instead of Kotlin's Retrofit? Retrofit changes the messages with OK and Conflict

Tags: android, kotlin, request, retrofit, response

I use **Kotlin** with **retrofit2** to achieve the **POST** request. The request is successful.

**The problem:** I've described all messages at my NodeJS server, but all I receive is **"OK"** or **"Conflict"** with `retrofit2`. I want to send the request and use it, but I **DO NOT** want to let the **retrofit** rewrite my `response.message()`

Tried to access the Response file of the library, but it has read-only access.

**I did all requests for iOS, Postman before. The server is ok.**

**Model:**

```
package com...
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class ModelUserRegister (
    @SerializedName("username")     val user: String?,
    @SerializedName("email")        val email: String?,
    @SerializedName("dateOfBirth")  val birth: String?,
    @SerializedName("male")         val male: Boolean?,
    @SerializedName("phone")        val phone: String?,
    @SerializedName("password")     val pas: String?,
    @SerializedName("ref")          val ref: String?
)
```

**ServiceBuilder:**

```
package com...
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.104:5000/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}
```

**RestApiService**:

```
package com...
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class RestApiService {

    fun addUser(userData: ModelUserRegister, onResult: (ModelUserRegister?, String?)-> Unit){
        println(userData)

        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)
        retrofit.addUser(userData).enqueue(

            object : Callback<ModelUserRegister> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ModelUserRegister>, t: Throwable) {
                    onResult(null, "Failure!")
                    println(t)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ModelUserRegister>, response: Response<ModelUserRegister>) {
                    val addedUser = response.body()

                    println("RESPONSE: ------- : \n$response")
                    println("HEADER: ------ : \n"+response.headers())
                    println("BODY: ------ : \n"+response.body())
                    println("MESSAGE: ------ : \n"+response.message())
                    println("ERROR MESSAGE: ------ : \n"+response.errorBody())

                    onResult(addedUser, response.message())
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
val apiService = RestApiService()
val userInfo = ModelUserRegister(
    user = tfName.text.toString(),
    email = tfEmail.text.toString(),
    birth = tfDate.text.toString(),
    male = male,
    phone = tfPhone.text.toString(),
    pas = tfPass1.text.toString(),
    ref = code
)

// my callback result for message = 's'
apiService.addUser(userInfo) { modelUserRegister: ModelUserRegister?, s: String? ->
    if (s != null) {
        alert(s)
    } else {
        alert("No message")
    }
}
```

**The results:**

```
I/System.out: ModelUserRegister(user=alex, email=johndoe@gmail.com, birth=12/12/1992, male=true, phone=38 (555) 334-12, pas=123456, ref=null)
I/System.out: 200 OK
    RESPONSE: ------- : 
    Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://192.168.0.104:5000/api/reg}
    HEADER: ------ : 
    X-Powered-By: Express
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 238
    ETag: W/"ee-QTG+VHdC8TC3kxGPcax9kzY3B20"
    Date: Sun, 24 Jan 2021 11:33:48 GMT
    Connection: keep-alive
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5
    BODY: ------ : 
    ModelUserRegister(user=null, email=null, birth=null, male=null, phone=null, pas=null, ref=null)
    MESSAGE: ------ : 
    OK
I/System.out: ERROR MESSAGE: ------ : 
    null
```

**Now:** `MESSAGE: OK.` **Should be:** `MESSAGE: The user successfully added to the database!`

01-26 10:13:25.300 19294-19294/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10058: Read-only file system
01-26 10:13:25.300 19294-19294/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
01-26 10:

```
13:25.301 19294-19294/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-26 10:13:25.456 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-26 10:13:25.472 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
01-26 10:13:25.472 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
01-26 10:13:25.594 19294-19312/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-26 10:13:25.594 19294-19312/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
01-26 10:14:08.663 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
01-26 10:14:08.663 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text
01-26 10:14:30.111 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/System.out: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=409, message=Conflict, url=http://192.168.0.104:5000/api/auth/register}
01-26 10:14:30.112 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/System.out: null
01-26 10:14:30.112 19294-19294/com.jaskierltd.goodtogether I/System.out: 409
```

Comment: please check with filter `okhttp`

Comment: please add  `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            client.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                .apply {
                    level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
                })
        }` after the `private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()`

Comment: it will show the request and response json in logcat

Answer (score 0):

Right now the API method is like this, which is not the approach.

```
addUser(userData:ModelUserRegister):Response<ModelUserRegister>
```

It should be

```
addUser(userData:ModelUserRegister):Response<RegisterResponse>
```

The response you should be returning is

```
{
  "STATUS": true,
  "MESSAGE": "The user successfully added to the database!"
}
```

The class should look like the below.

```
class ModelUserRegister {
    @SerializedName("STATUS")
    @Expose
    var sTATUS: Boolean = false

    @SerializedName("MESSAGE")
    @Expose
    var mESSAGE: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Tried to change everything according the new serialized values, however I don't get the expected result... How this should help if retrofit already changed the values we receive?

Comment: Let me add node js response, then you can relate to it.

Comment: **let msg = json["message"].string** for iOS goes perfectly for all responses.
The problem is not the server. It's about retrofit. It takes my original request response and replace it. Am I doing the decoding/deserialization wrong?

Comment: Well can you check the android studio logcat with filter `okhttp`, check what response you are getting, can you add that response json to the question

Comment: No matches for okhttp filters. I've added the println for response and code.

Comment: **message=Conflict**. It's here: **import retrofit2.Response.** The code replaces with "OK" or "CONFLICT" according to success. Is it possible to prevent?